# If names match, take file with longer name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have some batch script code to recursively copy the contents of a folder and its sub-folders into a singular folder :

```
for /r %f in (*) do @copy "%f" .
```

I would like to change the behavior slightly, so that if two or more files have the same name, I would like to copy only the one which has the longest file path (in terms of how many levels deep it is, not the character length).

eg if we had :

```
C:/Desktop/Folder/File1
```

and

```
C:/Desktop/Folder/NewFolder/File1
```

in this case, we would take the second file and copy it into the new folder.

I don't *believe* this is possible with a batch script, though I may be incorrect in this.

Thanks.

Comment: you are already there, because `FOR /R` will recurse from top to bottom, you will end with the deepest file just by force overwriting previously copied files, with `copy "%f" %dest% /Y`

Comment: @PA. you should just make that into the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may be already there, because `FOR /R` will recurse *in the same branch* from top to bottom, you will end with the deepest file just by force overwriting previously copied files

```
for /r %f in (*) do @copy /Y "%f" \destination
```

Comment: This is not correct. `\test\a\b\c\d\e\f\g\data.txt` is deeper than `\test\x\a\b\data.txt` but the first is iterated before the second

Comment: @MCND : even then not really. The order on a FAT drive is likely to be creation-order, not alphabetic as would be the case with NTFS, so \x... may be scanned before \test\a... This serves to complicate matters further.

Comment: @Magoo, yes, i know it, but this is just a sample (bad explained, you are right) of why the indicated answer could not work. Iteration is not done by levels but by branches. And a later processed brach can have less levels than a previously iterated one.

Comment: you're right, it will only overwrite the deepest in the same branch; but the latest in different branches. EDITED to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

The copy operations in this code are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` command before `copy`

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

:: CONFIGURATION

    rem Source and target folders for copy operation
    set "sourceFolder=%cd%"
    set "targetFolder=x:\somewhere"

    rem Temporary files needed 
    set "tempList=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%.tmp"
    set "endList=%tempList%.end"

    rem Variable used for level padding
    set "level=10000"


:: SEARCH FILES

    rem For each folder under the indicated source 
    (for /r "%sourceFolder%" /d %%a in (.) do (

        rem Retrieve the deep level splitting the folder name
        rem and counting the segments
        set "folder=%%a"
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & for %%b in ("!folder:\=" "!") do set /a "level+=1"

        rem For each file in the folder output filename, level and full file path
        rem A pipe character is used as delimiter between the tokens
        for %%b in (!level!) do (
            endlocal 
            for %%c in ("%%~fa\*") do (echo(^|%%~nxc^|%%b^|%%~fc)
        )

        rem And send everything to a temporary file
    )) > "%tempList%"

    rem Sort the temporary file on filename and level in descending order. 
    sort /r "%tempList%" /o "%endList%"

    rem Now for each group of files with same name, the first one is the 
    rem file located in the deepest folder


:: COPY FILES    

    rem No file has been copied 
    set "lastFile=|"

    rem For each record in the sorted file list, split it in three tokens
    rem using the included pipe charactes as delimiters
    for /f "usebackq tokens=1-3 delims=|" %%a in ("%endList%") do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        for %%d in ("!lastFile!") do (
            endlocal

            rem If the name of the file is different to 
            rem the previous one, we have started a new group and as the first file
            rem is the deepest one, copy it and store the new file name 
            if not "%%a"=="%%~d" (
                echo copy /y "%%c" "%targetFolder%"
                set "lastFile=%%a"
            )
        )
    )

:: CLEANUP

    rem Remove the temporary files 
    del /q "%tempList%"
    del /q "%endList%"
```